# Why doesn't clang show color output under Scons?

Tags: c++, clang, scons

When building with Scons, I can configure it to use clang like so:

```
env["CXX"] = "clang++"
```

However, it doesn't seem to preserve the color information that clang outputs. How can I make scons preserve the color?

Comment: You mean: how do you make *scons* preserve the format output [...] ?

Comment: This also applies to gcc with `-fdiagnostics-color=auto`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to the [clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#formatting-of-diagnostics), color is enabled only *when a color-capable terminal is detected*. SCons doesn't automatically pass on all environment variables to the process that runs the compiler, you have pass them explicitly. And TERM is not passed on to clang.

Add the following to your SConstruct and color should work again:

```
import os
env['ENV']['TERM'] = os.environ['TERM']
```

Comment: For me it even fails to work for simple make (Makefile generated by qmake).
It used to work before, no clue what could have changed (TERM=xterm) :/

Comment: Is this still the recommended solution? I tried it but clang still will not produce color with my terminal and scons. TERM for me is 'xterm-256color'. When I try 'clang++ -fcolor-diagnostics' I see color.

Comment: This still works fine with clang 3.7 and scons 2.4.1 using those TERM settings (also works with TERM=screen inside tmux) must be something else that is causing your issues.

Comment: Doesn't work when running scons in a docker container. I'm compiling with gcc and I've made sure the environment variables GCC_COLORS and TERM are set correctly in the container (by passing them to the docker command with -e option), but still, gcc for some strange reason thinks there isn't a proper terminal within the container. Any solutions?