# Using Clang's scan-build with scons and C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, scons, scan-build

I've added everything to my `$PATH` and I've tweaked my `SConstruct` to set the appropriate environment variables, as per these answers [ [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9922521/478288), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9305378/478288), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13179467/478288) ]. Now when I run

```
scan-build --use-c++=`which clang++` scons
```

the build begins, and I can see the process forked by `scons` is

```
/path/to/c++-analyzer ... -std=c++11 ...
```

The object file successfully builds, but then I get an error:

```
could not find clang line
```

This error occurs in `c++-analyzer` when the forked process does not contain the string `-cc1`. But if I check `ps aux`, I clearly see

```
/path/to/clang -cc1 ...
```

How could the program build properly but the static analyzer fail like this?

---

For reference, if I manually run

```
scan-build clang++ <parameters from scons>
```

then the build succeeds and the report is generated!

I can also "cheat" by adding

```
env["ENV"]["PATH"] = os.environ["PATH"]
```

and then running

```
CXX="scan-build clang++" scons
```

I just can't run `scan-build` on `scons` itself with an unmodified `SConstruct`.

Comment: Your question is answered in the first linked answer: "SCons normally cleans out the environment before running a build (this is a feature)."

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant I already use the environment variables that Greg suggests. I can *build* via Clang and SCons just fine; I can't run the *static analyzer*.

Comment: Hmm, try with scan-build --use-analyzer=/path/to/clang

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant `--use-analyzer` isn't a recognized option for `scan-build`.

Comment: that option was added to clang in Fri Aug 24 23:08:08 2012 with commit msg "Rework how scan-build picks the version of clang to use for static analysis", and released with clang 3.2

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant I finally got Clang 3.2 and tried the `--use-analyzer`. I still get the same error. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: Intresting... I manually compiled and installed the clang, and I have the same error message, but I did not used scons but a similar one, called waf. I have to use the --use-analyzer=/path/to/clang and that path must contain the binary itself, not just the path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that clang is not on the search path in the [execution environment (Wayback Machine)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130912091915/http://scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/x1750.html). This explains why adding the line `env["ENV"]["PATH"] = os.environ["PATH"]` solves the issue.

To run `scan-build` on an unmodified `SConstruct` you can put the clang executable (`clang++` and possibly `clang`) on the search path used by the execution environment, e.g. by creating a symbolic link from `/usr/bin/clang++` to your `/path/to/clang++` on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I had the identical problem: the object file successfully builds, but then I got the error:

```sh
could not find clang line
```

The problem was that I was using a flag valid for `gcc` but invalid for `clang`.

```sh
touch empty.c

scan-build gcc -fdiagnostics-show-caret -c empty.c
scan-build: Using '/usr/bin/clang-8.exe' for static analysis
could not find clang line
...

scan-build --use-cc=clang gcc -fdiagnostics-show-caret -c empty.c
scan-build: Using '/usr/bin/clang-8.exe' for static analysis
clang-8: error: unknown argument: '-fdiagnostics-show-caret'
...
```

Removing the `-fdiagnostics-show-caret` makes the problem go away:

```sh
scan-build gcc -c empty.c
scan-build: Using '/usr/bin/clang-8.exe' for static analysis
...
```

Also, to muddy the waters, `clang`'s name for this switch is `-fcaret-diagnostics`, which `gcc` will not accept.

Comment: **Edit:** I should note that `scan-build -v -v -v` here showed only a minimal amount of information, and it was not helpful.